# Elegant way of preventing div overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code:

```css
.wrapper {
  border-top: 2px solid #C0C0C0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #C0C0C0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 9vh;
  display: flex;
}

.leftDiv {
  height: 9vh;
  margin-left: 1vw;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.top {
  margin-top: 2vh;
  font-size: 2.6vh;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.bottom {
  font-size: 1.9vh;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.rightDiv {
  background-color: red;
  width: 20%;
  height: 9vh;
  float: right;
  border-left: 2px silver solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="leftDiv">
    <p class="top"><b>this cannot overflow right div  txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt</b></p>
    <p class="bottom">txt</p>
  </div>
  <div class="rightDiv"></div>
</div>
```

Jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/a4zuv1n5/

Here's what I am trying to do:
[image]

When leftDiv text(the top class) overflows rightDiv div, just a little before that,
I want a few dots to appear and replace the "txt" overflow. the dots should be manipulatable via javascript, I want to attach an event to them in javascript later on.
 how do I achieve this? is it possible? javascript is probably required here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You just linked my jsfiddle with no edits? well I do need to manipulate those dots with javascript in order to expand content

Comment: @WizardCoder If you're going to fix OP's problems with their code and show them, you should do it in an answer, not as a comment. That's what answers are for.

Answer (score 2):

Look at `text-overflow: ellipsis`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

Edit: Update the answer.

Ok, lets start from the beginning. Your css is all over the place. I've boiled this down to the basics in this codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BZpKOx

html

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="leftDiv"> 
        <p class="top">
          this cannot overflow right div  txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt this cannot overflow right div  txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt this cannot overflow right div  txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt
      </p>
      <p class="bottom">txt</p>
    </div>
    <div class="rightDiv">
      Stuff in the right
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.wrapper {
  outline: 1px solid #000;
  display: flex;
}
.leftDiv {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.leftDiv .top {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.rightDiv {
  outline: 1px solid #cc0000;
  width: 20%;
}
```

To get the clickable effect you mentioned, that can be as simple as creating an absolutely positioned element (div or anchor) with right: 0 and vertically positioned to overlay the ellipsis.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in my case... I applied all examples to my top class. besides, how do I turn that into a href link?

Comment: @RunningFromShia Shia surprise? Wrap it in a <href> tag.

Comment: WizardCoder, I will need those dots to be clickable as I intened to attatch an event to them with jquery...

Comment: Ok, no links I get it. but it doesn't even work in my example. the jsFiddle you sent is mine and it has no edits :S I applied text-overflow: ellipsis; everywhere and it didnt work.

Comment: I forgot to click update on the fiddledy diddle. Check now. https://jsfiddle.net/a4zuv1n5/1/

Comment: Geius I just seen your updated answer. it is good, but how can i manipulate these dots with javascript? this doesn't bring much use to me if i can't do anything with them javascript-wise. they do not even appear on the html source, only on the webpage, which means jquery won't even find them..

Comment: @RunningFromShia because you don't manipulate them at all. They are only a client-generated effect. To make them "clickable", look at my last couple sentences after the code examples.

Comment: I couldn't make that anchor work. reason being I don't know where these dots will appear. anyways thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Apply `overflow:hidden;` and `text-overflow: ellipsis;` to the `<p class="top">` element.

This is because the text you want to overflow is **not** a direct child of the `<div class="leftDiv">`, but it *is* a direct child of the `<p class="top">` element.

See this in this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a4zuv1n5/3/

Comment: thank you, but how can i manipulate these dots? this doesn't bring much use to me if i can't do anything with them javascript-wise. they do not even appear on the html source, only on the webpage, which means jquery won't even find them

Comment: I don't have time to implement this right now, but you could look into this plugin instead? https://github.com/bramstein/text-overflow/